# How to put a FancyBox slideshow on a Google Map marker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fancybox

I use this javascript to pop up a fancyBox on a Google Map marker:

```
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
            $.fancybox({
              href: 'img/2b.jpg'
              // other options

                });     
            });
```

And is working fine.

Here is an example:

http://jsbin.com/ANuyojoW/9/edit

But i don't know how can i put a slideshow instead of a simple image.
Do you know how can i do that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the gallery (slideshow) inside the fancybox script like :

```
$.fancybox([{
    href: "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3712/9032543579_1217e6566b_b.jpg",
    title: "fist title"
}, {
    href: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Tootsi_jaamahoone.jpg/800px-Tootsi_jaamahoone.jpg',
    title: "second title"
}, {
    href: "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3818/9036037912_83576fe5ab_b.jpg",
    title: "third title"
}], {
    // API other options
    padding: 0 // optional
}); // fancybox
```

Comment: God bless you! It was all the day i was trying to make it working!